# Momentum does not work in my Gradient Descent algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am developing my ANN *from scratch* which is supposed to classify [MNIST database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr66x.png) of handwritten digits (0-9). My feed-forward fully connected ANN *has to be* composed of:

1. One input layer, with `28x28=784` nodes (that is, features of each image)
2. One hidden layer, with any number of neurons (shallow network)
3. One output layer, with `10` nodes (one for each digit)

and *has to* compute gradient w.r.t. weights and bias thanks to *backpropagation* algorithm and, finally, it should learn exploiting *gradient descent with momentum* algorithm.

The loss function is: `cross_entropy` on "`softmax`ed" network's outputs, since the task is about *classification*.

Each hidden neuron is activated by the same activation function, I've chosen the `relu`; meanwhile the output's neurons are activated by the `identity` function.

The dataset has been divided into:

1. `50.000` training pairs `(image, label)` - for the training
2. `10.000` validation pairs `(image, label)` - for evaluation and select the network which minimize the validation loss
3. `10.000` testing pairs `(image, label)` - for testing the model picked using new metrics such as accuracy

These are my model's performance while setting `momentum=0`:

```
E(0) train_loss: 2.301786738121001 val_loss: 2.2994577097345617 val_acc: 23.56 %
E(1) train_loss: 2.2991744480572343 val_loss: 2.296530889826395 val_acc: 29.89 %
E(2) train_loss: 2.296323002364101 val_loss: 2.293134932028432 val_acc: 41.61 %
E(3) train_loss: 2.292997264176795 val_loss: 2.2892840055440327 val_acc: 51.93 %
E(4) train_loss: 2.289205636611801 val_loss: 2.284964446087791 val_acc: 57.940000000000005 %
E(5) train_loss: 2.2849313671784017 val_loss: 2.2800769150410987 val_acc: 61.39 %
...
E(20) train_loss: 2.128675183264704 val_loss: 2.1153764655253786 val_acc: 71.5 %
E(21) train_loss: 2.115737487239871 val_loss: 2.103016381586049 val_acc: 71.81 %
E(22) train_loss: 2.1033723914989033 val_loss: 2.09129407935966 val_acc: 72.2 %
E(23) train_loss: 2.0916433841088193 val_loss: 2.0802291350772184 val_acc: 72.64 %
E(24) train_loss: 2.0805733252196545 val_loss: 2.0698172384698634 val_acc: 73.1 %
E(25) train_loss: 2.07015863838244 val_loss: 2.0600228749852607 val_acc: 73.66 %
E(26) train_loss: 2.060366249549054 val_loss: 2.050812363686796 val_acc: 74.08 %
E(27) train_loss: 2.0511624437505502 val_loss: 2.0421217005452292 val_acc: 74.44 %
E(28) train_loss: 2.0424852700109315 val_loss: 2.033921555913856 val_acc: 75.01 %
E(29) train_loss: 2.0343013393831604 val_loss: 2.0261291568059194 val_acc: 75.44 %
E(30) train_loss: 2.0265347059971788 val_loss: 2.018748492117326 val_acc: 75.97 %
...
E(49) train_loss: 1.9430938246889078 val_loss: 1.9329753111083592 val_acc: 81.16 %
Validation loss is minimum at epoch 49
Accuracy score on test set is: 81.81 %
```

[image: losses]

As you can see when `momentum=0` my learning rule is the (vanilla) gradient descent. Unfortunately when I set `momentum=0.9` (or any other value), the learning seems not the work properly:

```
E(0) train_loss: 2.302783139685314 val_loss: 2.2992788953305396 val_acc: 19.950000000000003 %
E(1) train_loss: 2.2993850383518213 val_loss: 2.2848443220743024 val_acc: 20.979999999999997 %
E(2) train_loss: 2.2852413073649185 val_loss: 2.2245098593332324 val_acc: 24.29 %
E(3) train_loss: 2.2256566385909484 val_loss: 2.052373637528151 val_acc: 34.74 %
E(4) train_loss: 2.054457510557211 val_loss: 1.7725185209449252 val_acc: 38.74 %
E(5) train_loss: 1.7750945816727548 val_loss: 4.766960950639445 val_acc: 23.73 %
...
E(20) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(21) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(22) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(23) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(24) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(25) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(26) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(27) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(28) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(29) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
E(30) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
...
E(49) train_loss: 629.5534744116509 val_loss: 629.269795928194 val_acc: 11.27 %
Validation loss is minimum at epoch 4
Accuracy score on test set is: 11.360000000000001 %
```

[image: with momentum]

What am I missing? What's the problem? The *Gradient Descent with momentum* formula is:

[image: momentum formula]

This is my code:

```
from mnist.loader import MNIST
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

import numpy as np

def accuracy_score(targets, predictions):
    predictions = softmax(predictions)
    correct_predictions = 0
    for item in range(np.shape(predictions)[1]):
        argmax_idx = np.argmax(predictions[:, item])
        if targets[argmax_idx, item] == 1:
            correct_predictions += 1
    return correct_predictions / np.shape(predictions)[1]


def one_hot(targets):
    return np.asmatrix(np.eye(10)[targets]).T

def plot(epochs, loss_train, loss_val):
    plt.plot(epochs, loss_train)
    plt.plot(epochs, loss_val, color="orange")
    plt.legend(["Training Loss", "Validation Loss"])
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


def identity(a, derivative=False):
    f_a = a
    if derivative:
        return np.ones(np.shape(a))
    return f_a


def relu(a, derivative=False):
    f_a = np.maximum(0, a)
    if derivative:
        return (a > 0) * 1
    return f_a

def softmax(y):
    epsilon = 10 ** -308
    e_y = np.exp(y - np.max(y, axis=0))
    sm = e_y / np.sum(e_y, axis=0)
    return np.clip(sm, epsilon, 1 - epsilon)

def cross_entropy(y, t, derivative=False, post_process=True):
    if post_process:
        if derivative:
            return y - t
        sm = softmax(y)
        item_loss = -np.sum(np.multiply(t, np.log(sm)), axis=0)
        return np.mean(item_loss)


class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = []

    def add(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)

    def build(self):
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
            if i == 0:
                layer.type = "input"
            else:
                layer.type = "output" if i == len(self.layers) - 1 else "hidden"
                layer.configure(self.layers[i - 1].neurons)


    def fit(self, X_train, targets_train, X_val, targets_val, max_epochs=50):
        e_loss_train = []
        e_loss_val = []

        # Getting the minimum loss on validation set
        predictions_val = self.predict(X_val)
        min_loss_val = cross_entropy(predictions_val, targets_val)

        best_net = self  # net which minimize validation loss
        best_epoch = 0  # epoch where the validation loss is minimum

        # batch mode
        for epoch in range(max_epochs):
            predictions_train = self.predict(X_train)
            self.back_prop(targets_train, cross_entropy)
            self.learning_rule(l_rate=0.000005, momentum=0.9)
            loss_train = cross_entropy(predictions_train, targets_train)
            e_loss_train.append(loss_train)

            # Validation
            predictions_val = self.predict(X_val)
            loss_val = cross_entropy(predictions_val, targets_val)
            e_loss_val.append(loss_val)

            print(f"E({epoch}) "
                  f"train_loss: {loss_train} "
                  f"val_loss: {loss_val} "
                  f"val_acc: {accuracy_score(targets_val, predictions_val) * 100} %")

            if loss_val < min_loss_val:
                min_loss_val = loss_val
                best_epoch = epoch
                best_net = self

        print(f"Validation loss is minimum at epoch {best_epoch}")

        plot(np.arange(max_epochs), e_loss_train, e_loss_val)

        return best_net

    # Matrix of predictions where the i-th column corresponds to the i-th item
    def predict(self, dataset):
        z = dataset
        for layer in self.layers:
            z = layer.forward_prop_step(z)
        return z

    def back_prop(self, target, loss):
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers[:0:-1]):
            next_layer = self.layers[-i]
            prev_layer = self.layers[-i - 2]
            layer.back_prop_step(next_layer, prev_layer, target, loss)

    def learning_rule(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        for layer in [layer for layer in self.layers if layer.type != "input"]:
            layer.update_weights(l_rate, momentum)
            layer.update_bias(l_rate, momentum)


class Layer:

    def __init__(self, neurons, type=None, activation=None):
        self.dE_dW = None  # derivatives dE/dW where W is the weights matrix
        self.dE_db = None  # derivatives dE/db where b is the bias
        self.dact_a = None  # derivative of the activation function
        self.out = None  # layer output
        self.weights = None  # input weights
        self.bias = None  # layer bias
        self.w_sum = None  # weighted_sum
        self.neurons = neurons  # number of neurons
        self.type = type  # input, hidden or output
        self.activation = activation  # activation function
        self.deltas = None  # for back-prop
        self.diff_w = None  # for momentum
        self.diff_b = None  # for momentum

    def configure(self, prev_layer_neurons):
        self.set_activation()
        self.weights = np.asmatrix(np.random.uniform(-0.02, 0.02, (self.neurons, prev_layer_neurons)))
        self.bias = np.asmatrix(np.random.uniform(-0.02, 0.02, self.neurons)).T
        self.diff_w = np.asmatrix(np.zeros(shape=np.shape(self.weights)))
        self.diff_b = np.asmatrix(np.zeros(shape=np.shape(self.bias)))

    def set_activation(self):
        if self.activation is None:
            if self.type == "hidden":
                self.activation = relu
            elif self.type == "output":
                self.activation = identity

    def forward_prop_step(self, z):
        if self.type == "input":
            self.out = z
        else:
            self.w_sum = np.dot(self.weights, z) + self.bias
            self.out = self.activation(self.w_sum)
        return self.out

    def back_prop_step(self, next_layer, prev_layer, target, local_loss):
        if self.type == "output":
            self.dact_a = self.activation(self.w_sum, derivative=True)
            self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a,
                                      local_loss(self.out, target, derivative=True))
        else:
            self.dact_a = self.activation(self.w_sum, derivative=True)  # (m,batch_size)
            self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a, np.dot(next_layer.weights.T, next_layer.deltas))

        self.dE_dW = self.deltas * prev_layer.out.T

        self.dE_db = np.sum(self.deltas, axis=1)

    def update_weights(self, l_rate, momentum):
        self.weights = self.weights - l_rate * self.dE_dW + momentum * self.diff_w
        self.diff_w = np.copy(self.weights)

        # Vanilla GD
        # self.weights = self.weights - l_rate * self.dE_dW

    def update_bias(self, l_rate, momentum):
        self.bias = self.bias - l_rate * self.dE_db + momentum * self.diff_b
        self.diff_b = np.copy(self.bias)

        # Vanilla GD
        # self.bias = self.bias - l_rate * self.dE_db


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mndata = MNIST(path="data", return_type="numpy")
    X_train, targets_train = mndata.load_training()  # 60.000 images, 28*28 features
    X_test, targets_test = mndata.load_testing()  # 10.000 images, 28*28 features

    X_train, targets_train = shuffle(X_train, targets_train.T)

    # Data pre processing
    X_train = X_train / 255  # normalization within [0;1]
    X_test = X_test / 255  # normalization within [0;1]
    X_train = X_train.T  # data transposition
    X_test = X_test.T  # data transposition

    # Split
    X_val, X_train = np.hsplit(X_train, [10000])
    targets_val, targets_train = np.hsplit(targets_train, [10000])
   
    # One hot
    targets_train = one_hot(targets_train)
    targets_val = one_hot(targets_val)
    targets_test = one_hot(targets_test)

    net = NeuralNetwork()
    d = np.shape(X_train)[0]  # number of features, 28x28
    c = np.shape(targets_train)[0]  # number of classes, 10

    # Net creation
    for m in (d, 100, c):
        net.add(Layer(m))

    net.build()

    best_net = net.fit(X_train, targets_train, X_val, targets_val, max_epochs=50)

    # Testing
    predictions_test = best_net.predict(X_test)
    accuracy_test = accuracy_score(targets_test, predictions_test)
    print(f"Accuracy score on test set is: {accuracy_test * 100} %")
```

Comment: Check your momentum update, `diff_w` should probably store the _update_ of the weights, whereas you are storing the weights themselves. Same for bias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @xdurch0 the update rule is invalid

```
def update_weights(self, l_rate, momentum):
    self.weights = self.weights - l_rate * self.dE_dW + momentum * self.diff_w
    self.diff_w = np.copy(self.weights)

def update_bias(self, l_rate, momentum):
    self.bias = self.bias - l_rate * self.dE_db + momentum * self.diff_b
    self.diff_b = np.copy(self.bias)
```

should be

```
def update_weights(self, l_rate, momentum):
    self.diff_w = l_rate * self.dE_dW + momentum * self.diff_w
    self.weights = self.weights - self.diff_w

def update_bias(self, l_rate, momentum):
    self.diff_b = l_rate * self.dE_db + momentum * self.diff_b
    self.bias = self.bias - self.diff_b
```

Momentum means "apply the previous **update**" again, with slowly decaying factor in front of it.